# Get the actual target of a js href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I want to analyze all of the `href`s in a given `HTML` page.

Analyzing static and relative ones is easy with `document.links`.

However, when I have a js code in the `href`, it gets complicated. For example:

```
<head> 
 <SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
 <!--hide 
 function openwindow() 
 { 
   window.open('xyz.htm','jav','width=400,height=300,resizable=yes'); 
 } 
 //--> 
 </SCRIPT>
 <a href="javascript:openwindow()">Open a New Window</a>
 </head>
```

(code sample taken from https://blog.udemy.com/javascript-href/)

I would have liked to know that his certain anchor element is linking to 'xyz.htm'

Obviously, the number of ways to link to a different page in js is probably to vast to generalize. But is there some tool or trick to get as close as possible?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to know where the anchor element are linking to?

Comment: Basically impossible... In that sample, it can be done, but a more complicated one would not be possible without trying to basically write your own parser to walk the tree of code.

Comment: @Sleek Geek yes exactly